# Rewriting URL to a base directory from a parameter

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

This is the current HTACCESS code that I have and didn't work:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/d]+)/?$ index.php?id=$1 [QSA]
```

How can I make it where:

```
http://www.example.com/index.php?id=100
```

becomes:

```
http://www.example.com/100
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this in your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?id=$1 [L]
```

It will leave you with the URL: `http://www.example.com/100`. Make sure you clear your cache before testing this.

Comment: thanks it actually worked! i had to make a few edits since i was using it in a sub directory but overall it worked.